# css - too wide background

Tags: html, css, background

small problem with my css website. I'm converting my PS design to html5 and css3 site and it looks, that my background images for top and bottom of the page are too big (1600px). What should I do if I want to keep my entire site's look and feel?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is the problem exactly? Can you show us a bit of code and explain what is wrong and what you want? I don't think anybody can help you right now..

Comment: Put a http://jsfiddle.net/ up with an example, or some screen shots

Answer (score 1):

You make your css like below

```
body, elementID, elementClass{
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

whatever be the screen resolution of the user, your page or div or container will fit the screen.

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if your question was a bit clearer, but here goes:

How a website is viewed largely depends on the resolution of the screen that the visitor is using. For example, User A may have a resolution of 1920 x 1080. This means they can easily see all of your website. Whereas another user may only have 1024 x 768, which obviously isn't large enough to see all 1600 pixels!

To get around this largely depends on the design of your site, are the backgrounds something that can be repeated (such as a gradient), or is it something a bit tricky such as a skyline?

If it's simple, you can use CSS to repeat the background horizontally, vertically, or both.

You can also position a background using CSS (Such as top center), which will center your background, cutting off the edges that go over the screen sides while keeping the middle part in view.

In CSS3, you also get a property called "background-size" which allows you to define how the background reacts. There are several values this can have, these are:

- *cover* - this makes sure the whole image fits within it's container (so that the whole image is visible).
- *contain* - this makes the image fit the entire container, so parts of it may not be visible.
- *dimensionx dimensiony* - If you specify a value/percentage, the first value/percentage will be the width, the second one is the height. If only one is supplied, it is used for the width and the height is set to auto.

Please note that background-size is not supported in all browsers.

A demo of background-size: http://davidwalsh.name/demo/background-size.html